# Drop element on Cursor position

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am doing drag n drop event in that I want to drop the element on droppable element.

```
<div class="draggable ui-draggable"  id="800068">
    <h5>test 2.mp4</h5>
</div>
```

I am dropping it into ::

```
<div class="drop" data-bind:"foreach:items">
   <div class="slot">
        <p data-bind="text"></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

& my Jquery code for drag & drop is as::

```
$('.draggable').draggable();
$('.drop').droppable();
```

But the Dropped element is appended at bottom of the   & I want to append that dropped element in the Way `so that I can be over Slot as well as over <p>`

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what the problem is, could you put together a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/yLd4j/   
Here I am trying to drop the Element in Between two different DIV blocks

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".slot").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        tolerance:"pointer",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = this;
            $(dropped).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 });
            $(droppedOn).before($(dropped));
            $(dropped).append("<h5></h5>");
            $(dropped).find('h5').text("hello test");
        }
    });
```

This will put it below the div it was dropped on if that is what you want?

Comment: How can I put it on Upper of the DIV??